# How much IOPS is recommended for large file read and write

Tags: iops, azure-storage

How to select the number of IOPS required for processing a large file (hundreds of GB) in Azure Hybrid Disk?

I am using Azure blob storage for storing compressed (zstd) disk image backup  (1TB disk size, approx. 450 GB after compressing) and I want to verify the integrity by decompressing them, checking MD5 checksum, mounting that image (losetup) and verifying the integrity of some files inside that image.

I want to transfer a backup file from Azure Storage (blob) Container to VM in Azure with Ultra Disk (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/managed-disks/). Because zstd is fast I want to set throughput to 1000MB/s but I don't know how to efficiently select how much IOPS do I need?

Comment: choose a iops count and if its too low increase it?